# Best way to link to javascript

Tags: javascript

Very simple question here that I have not found the answer to despite searching a lot.

Whats the easiest way to load/call a piece of java script that is saved outside of the file.  So that several pages could use the same piece of java script, as though that piece of script was actually loaded into each page's head?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Just make it so that I can put one bit of code in a file, and have several pages load it. Like how many html pages can load the same CSS file for their formatting.

Comment: Some references: http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/external_javascript_file.cfm  http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/external.shtml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579883/using-external-javascript-files-in-a-js-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it in your file system and use relative paths from your current directory to locate it (eg. up one level - ../):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../somefile.js"></script>
```

And add this anywhere in your desired file. (Convention says either in the `<head>` or before `</body>` (before the body ends))

Comment: Generally just before the closing body is the best placement for performance reasons and to guarantee that the DOM elements you wish to change exist when the script is run. As a FYI for gibsonman507, the type attribute is no longer necessary if the doctype is HTML5. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type

Comment: @pwdst I was aware of the html5 documentation but was just including it for convention sake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just save this piece of JavaScript code in a separated file, i.e. `myscript.js` and link it using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "script" tag is part of the DOM.

You can add the tag like any other tag.

If you use jquery then it could look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var file = ? //Somehow acquire your new JS filename

   $("head").append("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + file + "'></script>");

});
```

You could have all your client dependencies defined server-side like in a configuration file or in the database. So, the first thing you'd need to do is query your server for your javascript dependencies.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
      url: "some.url",
      type: "get",
      datatype: "json",
      success: function(data){

          for(var i = 0; i < data.clientDependencies.length;i++)
          {
               var jsfile = data.clientDependencies[i].fileName;
               $("head").append("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + jsfile + "'></script>");
          }          

      }

   });

});
```

Your server would then have to return the following JSON structure

```
{ "clientDependencies" : 
   [ 
     { "fileName" : "one.js" },
     { "fileName" : "two.js" } 
   ]
}
```

Note: This will still minimally require you to have jquery script tag hardcoded in your html page but all other js dependencies can be loaded as shown above.

Another technique is to have your server merge all your javascript files into one file and then serve that file to your client. Your server would then have control over what client dependencies is needed depending on what the client is asking for.

But honestly, nowadays, the internet is so fast that, in most cases, it's just less of hassle to just include all script tags in your html page from the get go.

Comment: Has to be the most complicated way I've ever seen to load JS.  I don't say this as a negative criticism, rather I think this is an interesting answer to the question.