# Getting the returned variables from an executed JavaScript/jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this simple code as part of a PHP file, the purpose of this code is to execute the job1.js file on the client side (has to be done so), in this file I have a function called `job1()` that returns 3 variable back. The returned variables must be passed to the Server for further work.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // $jobJSPath[0] holds the path to the job1.js file
        var scriptPath = "<?php echo $jobJSPath[0]; ?>"; 
        $.getScript(scriptPath, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            // Call the function
            job1();
            window.alert( data ); // Data, actually it has only the content of the file as a string
            window.alert( textStatus ); // Success
            window.alert( jqxhr.status ); // 200
        });
    });
</script>
```

The function is being executed without any problems, it’s doing some internal string operations (very boring :) ) and returns 3 variables back.

My question is how do I get the 3 return variables from the `job1()` function with their input back. I searched a lot and even tried

```
var result = eval('(' + data + ')');
console.log(result);
```

Because the `data` variable holds the function as a string but still without any success, this option was suggested on some other page on this site.

EDIT: the `data` and the `job1` have same text:

´function job1() {
        var text = "";
        var vocabulary = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
            text += vocabulary.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * vocabulary.length));
            }

    var subText1 = text.slice(0, Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length));

    var subText2 = text.slice(subText1.length, text.length);

    //test for output
    alert("This is JavaScript");

    var nextJob = "job2, job3";
    var prevJob = "null";

    return {
    text_RT : text,
    subText1_RT : subText1,
    subText2_RT : subText2
    };
```

}´

Comment: The server will not execute the js. When the js is executed on the client, make an ajax call to the server, passing the values for further processing.

Comment: It is a bit confusing, if function job1 is defined in job1.js then you need to "load" the js by adding a script tag in your document before you can execute it. ex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2579936/3802077

Comment: `function job1() {return [varone, vartwo, varthree];}` - `var job1Data = job1(); console.log(job1Data);`

Comment: @user3802077 that's precisely what getScript does.

Comment: The server doesn’t have to execute the js. only the client. I'm executing the  .js in my web browser on my pc with no problem. Do you have a good example of an Ajax call to the server passing the values the server?

Comment: @TalG Can you include text of `data` and `job1` function at Question?

Comment: Given that you're using jQuery, why don't you read the doco for $.ajax() for examples of sending data from client to server?

Comment: @guest271314 included

Comment: @TalG What does `var job = job1(); console.log(job)` og at `console`?

Comment: @guest271314 I get an object back with the labels `text_RT : correct content` , `subText1_RT : correct content` and  `subText2_RT : correct content` after that I get the ´_proto_ object` with lots of other info. It’s just too much to write here as a comment. `correct content` = a log string of chars created inside the function.

Comment: @TalG _"I get an object back with the labels `text_RT : correct content` , `subText1_RT : correct content` and `subText2_RT : correct content`"_ This resolves Question _"My question is how do I get the 3 return variables from the `job1()`"_, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 I guess it does :). Can I use the answer from Zlil Korman below to post the variables back to the server? Because the question implies the use of those variables back on the server side. If yes do I have to address their label names to do so?

Comment: _"Can I use the answer from Zlil Korman below to post the variables back to the server?"_ Have you tried the `js` at @ZlilKorman 's Answer?

Comment: @guest271314 Will do first thing in the morning and report back, thanks for your help!

Comment: @guest271314 I have put some new input at the end of the post

Comment: _"Will do first thing in the morning and report back"_ Does Answer by @ZlilKorman not return expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 Well I used it a bit differently because my results doesn't always have only 3 return parameters, therefore I have used the '$.each` function to build an array out of the returned `object`and then I wanted to post it buck to the same `PHP` page for further work with it using the `$_POST['resultArray'];`

Comment: @TalG Yes, though no `url` is set at `$.ajax()` call? That is, where is `$.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                data: {resultArray : result},
            });` posted to? Would be same url of `document` if no `url` is set? What is expected response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

java script is for the client side, php is for the server side, just use ajax call and pass the data using post, after job1() is done and you got the returned array, just use an ajax call like this:

```
var yourdata=job1();
var postdata= [{"1": yourdata[0], "2": yourdata[1], "3": yourdata[2]}];
    $.ajax({
    type: POST,
    data: postdata,
    url: "test.php", //stands for the php file you want to send the data to
    }).done(function() {
      //do something.....
    })

on the server side fetch the data using $_POST["1"] for example
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll check it out tomorrow and report back

Comment: I have put some new input at the end of the post

Answer (score 0):

Well that what I have until now

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // $jobJSPath[0] holds the path to the job1.js file
        var scriptPath = "<?php echo $jobJSPath[0]; ?>"; 
        $.getScript(scriptPath, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            // Call the function
            var job = job1();
            window.alert( data ); // Data, actually it has only the content of the file as a string
            console.log(job); // shows all the return parameters from job1();
            window.alert( textStatus ); // Success
            window.alert( jqxhr.status ); // 200
            //  push the return parameters into result array
            var result = [];
            $.each(job, function(index, value) {
                //window.alert(index + ": " + value);
                result.push(value);
            });
            // post the results back to the same page 
            $.ajax({        
            type: 'POST',
            data: {result : result},
            url: 'executedJobs.php',
            }).done(function(data) {
                var redirectUrl = "executedJobs.php";
                var form = $('<form action="' + redirectUrl + '" method="post">' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="result" value="'+ data +'" />' +
                '</form>');
                $('body').append(form);
                $(form).submit();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And after that to get the results on the the `executedJobs.php` page I used

```
<?php
$myArray = $_REQUEST['result'];
echo "myArray:<br/>";
print_r($myArray);
?>
```

It works that way, the only thing is I get the word `myArray` echoed twice every time before the `print_r($myArray);`.

Comment: @guest271314 do you know why is $myArray empty?

Comment: No `url` appears at `$.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                data: {resultArray : result},
            });`?

Comment: @guest271314 have put he `url:` but the `$myArray` is still empty and the `POST`has calld the same page with the code 200 and `content-lenght: 1041`

Comment: Did you `echo $myArray` at `php`? Also, no `.then()` or `.done()`  handles response from `$.ajax()`; e.g., `$.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                data: {resultArray : result},
                url: 'execJob.php' // remove trailing comma
            }).then(function(data) {console.log(data)}); `

Comment: @guest271314 I'm really new to this, what suppose to come in the `.then()` or `.done()` section?

Comment: The response from server : `$myArray` `echo`ed from `execJob.php`

Comment: @guest271314 I edited the code and now I'm getting `undefined` in the console when it executes the  `console.log(respServ);`the `console.log(data)` just shows me my code of the page

Comment: Did you `echo $myArray` at `php`?

Comment: @guest271314 the `console.log(data)' shows : <br/> myArray <br/>array(3) {[0]=>  string(500) "ugqPUNARH1egozypGlcfPmNCj NVf0loZBd3hOZZgawKJa8jboombPqJ20HQMsYPiAddogUCMRYapHBbV6TkK62  z16dPhBikOg0dIcUyn65YPZ1aWNef4M3evOXQRV Lnh6fOsPoV sMZ7rhfPGnDYK6a7VHnTRelL1NhUI0TVlhR9NdsNAA9wnO957T8NsLm96XY5LC8XPytqRzRuDJL0fr90gbmbG7Brxm4iVriWZIK2wNWqEO98Ta1CfZZ6Sd5h8B2iyG219EHHshpW65OVCwUBep7Uxi1og5tEj8CwRwPZA0LSTY4jrx7586ZSuXxCbzXJoBuEGFZAzA9JQG1iU70YH8xQH9uhAljdxH4ZCyRXyNYc2ccHxjHLOLm2IhLq12E0UrHRPdGUtva5wDPcrhzpW3pPClwh0TR6NT8VvWT3gBLS3q0mC3hfr99uu0pIQkNkou8VBfZMg9zEDsOP2qKhEypPw ebX7lcjxA q5F78"

Comment: [1]=>  string(17) "ugqPUNARH1egozypG"
  [2]=>  string(483) "lcfPmNCj NVf0loZBd3hOZZgawKJa8jboo mbPqJ20HQMsYPiAddogUCMRYapHBbV6TkK62  z16dPhBikOg0dIcUyn65YPZ1aWNef4M3evOXQRV Lnh6fOsPoV sMZ7rhfPGnDYK6a7VHnTRelL1NhUI0TVlhR9NdsNAA9wnO957T8NsLm96XY5LC8XPytqRzRuDJL0fr90gbmbG7Brxm4iVriWZIK2wNWqEO98Ta1CfZZ6Sd5h8B2iyG219EHHshpW65OVCwUBep7Uxi1og5tEj8CwRwPZA0LSTY4jrx7586ZSuXxCbzXJo WBuEGFZAzA9JQG1iU70YH8xQH9uhAljdxH4ZCyRXyNYc2ccHxjHLOLm2IhLq12E0UrHRPdGUtva5wDPcrhzpW3pPClwh0TR6NT8VvWT3gBLS3q0mC3hfr99uu0pIQkNkou8VBfZMg9zEDsOP2qKhEypPw ebX7lcjxA q5F78"
}

Comment: I did echoed the `$myArray` at but nothing shows on the page only the result of `var_dump($myArray);` witch is NULL

Comment: What should `data` be?

Comment: @guest271314 `data` should show the array from above array(3) {[0]=> string(500) 1]=> string(17) [2]=> string(483)`  with all their strings but I'm not seeing it in my `$myArray` in the `PHP` code

Comment: At http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130481/getting-the-returned-variables-from-an-executed-javascript-jquery-function/38149013?noredirect=1#comment63733666_38149013 `console.log(data)` returned expected result, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 yes the results from the `console.log(data)` are good but it shows a lot more than just my array it show the whole JavaScript code with it.

Comment: @guest271314 It looks like my `PHP` code is being executed before the whole `JavaScript` part and that's why my `$maArray` is empty.

Comment: At `php` : `echo $myArray`, at `javascript` : `.then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });`

Comment: @guest271314 I didn't understand your previous comment. I have some `PHP`code to pass staff to my `JavaScript` code and after the `JavaScript` code executes I have another `PHP` code under the `JavaScript` code to populate the `$myArray` variable. My `console.log(data)` at `JavaScript` shows me that the array was posted back on the page, but as far as the view of my page goes I don't see anything because my view of the page is not being refreshed and all the `PHP`sections of the code are being executed on the first load of the page before the execution of `JavaScript`code.

Comment: @guest271314 I would like to have the execution in this order: first `PHP`section => `JavaScript`code => second `PHP`section or anything else that will alow me do some stuff with `$myArray` later and see the results on the same page when I `echo` or `print_r()` them. I thank you very much that you are helping me so far!

Comment: @guest271314 I got something that works and I updated my Post, could you please look at the question at the end of if? I just don't understand why it happens. Is it because of the `POST` of the `Ajax` before the `.done()` section?