# How to import library into vue component?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Let's say there is component `ComponentA` and I am importing `libA` in it.

```
import libA from 'libA'
```

and `libA` needs `libB` loaded.
it works with If I load them in html:

```
<script url='libB url'/>
<script url='libA url'/>
```

But I'd like to import it in `ComponentA`.
I am new on ES6, webpack, babel, vue and components.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can’t import files from external URLs. [Using external javascript files in a .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579883/using-external-javascript-files-in-a-js-file)
 You can download the external script and Import or require them into your vue component or place them in your html file as a script tag.

I'm assuming you also mean `<script src='libB url' />` not `<script url='libB url' />`

-- edit ---

You can also use [webpack plugins](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) in your `build/webpack.prod.conf.js` and `build/webpack.dev.conf.js`. For example if your libB is jQuery for example you can add the following under your `plugins` array

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
}),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. actually the libraries are also in my package.json and node_modules. Yes right `src` :) sorry my bad

Comment: You can also in your 'webpack.prod.conf.js' and 'webpack.dev.conf.js' a new webpack plugin with the library as a global variable.  `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      Ladda: 'ladda',
      ladda: 'ladda',
      PNotify: 'PNotify'
    }),`

Comment: Thank you very much. I successfully imported threejs usind ur method but there is panolens library https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js/blob/master/build/panolens.js which is not exportable :( How can I deal with this?