# JS AzureSDK create custom function to capture speech, display the text results and a confidence level of the results

Tags: javascript, azure, speech-to-text, speech

I need to create a simple javascript function to capture the input, then return the text with a confidence percentage using AzureSDK.

My biggest problem is that I am new to coding and this is the most difficult issue I faced, so please be kind to this humble student.

I am building a language learning webapp using voice input. I have been able to get the google services to work the way I wanted but, unfortunately, those services don't work in China where my market is. I am also using Phaser 3 api to build this app.

I have been able to get the sample code provided on git for the AzureSDK speech to text javascript to work but when I try to create my own function with the code I get:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SpeechConfig' of undefined

I also do not know how to add a confidence level to the speech result.

```
recordButton.on('pointerdown', function() {
        var SDK =  window.SpeechSDK;
        try {
        AudioContext = window.AudioContext // our preferred impl
            || window.webkitAudioContext   // fallback, mostly for Safari
            || false;                      // could not find.
        if (AudioContext) {
            soundContext = new AudioContext();
          console.log("AudioContext", AudioContext);
        } else {
            alert("Audio context not supported");
        }
        }
        catch (e) {
         console.log("no sound context found, no audio output. " + e);
        }

        console.log("SpeechSDK initialized", SDK);

        speechConfig = 
          SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, 
           serviceRegion);

        speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
        console.log("speechConfig", SpeechConfig);      

        audioConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
        recognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, 
           audioConfig);
        recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(
        function (result) {
          console.log("result", result); 
          recognizer.close();
          recognizer = undefined;
        },
        function (err) {
          console.log(err);
          recognizer.close();
          recognizer = undefined;
        });
}, this);
```

I need to capture the speech input, then show the words/phrases/sentences the students have said and score them based on the confidence level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get confident score of the text value that you get from speech to text SDK ,try the code below :

```
   <html>
    <head>
       <title>Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</title>
    </head>
    <script src="microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js"></script>

<body>
 <div id="warning">
  <h1 style="font-weight:500;">Speech Recognition Speech SDK not found (microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js missing).</h1>
</div>

<div id="content" style="display:none">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><h1 style="font-weight:500;">Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started" target="_blank">Subscription</a>:</td>
      <td><input id="subscriptionKey" type="text" size="40" value="subscription"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Region</td>
      <td><input id="serviceRegion" type="text" size="40" value="YourServiceRegion"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><button id="startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton">Start recognition</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="top">Results</td>
      <td><textarea id="phraseDiv" style="display: inline-block;width:500px;height:200px"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>



<!-- Speech SDK USAGE -->
<script>
  // status fields and start button in UI
  var phraseDiv;
  var startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton;

  // subscription key and region for speech services.
  var subscriptionKey, serviceRegion;
  var authorizationToken;
  var SpeechSDK;
  var recognizer;

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton = document.getElementById("startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton");
    subscriptionKey = document.getElementById("subscriptionKey");
    serviceRegion = document.getElementById("serviceRegion");
    phraseDiv = document.getElementById("phraseDiv");

    startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton.disabled = true;
      phraseDiv.innerHTML = "";

      // if we got an authorization token, use the token. Otherwise use the provided subscription key
      var speechConfig;
      if (authorizationToken) {
        speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromAuthorizationToken(authorizationToken, serviceRegion.value);
      } else {
        if (subscriptionKey.value === "" || subscriptionKey.value === "subscription") {
          alert("Please enter your Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech subscription key!");
          return;
        }
        speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey.value, serviceRegion.value);
      }

      speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
      speechConfig.outputFormat=1;
      var audioConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
      recognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

      recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(
        function (result) {
          startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton.disabled = false;
          phraseDiv.innerHTML += "Recognize Result:"+ result.text + "\nConfidence Score:" + JSON.parse(result.json).NBest[0].Confidence;

          window.console.log(result);

          recognizer.close();
          recognizer = undefined;
        },
        function (err) {
          startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton.disabled = false;
          phraseDiv.innerHTML += err;
          window.console.log(err);

          recognizer.close();
          recognizer = undefined;
        });
    });

    if (!!window.SpeechSDK) {
      SpeechSDK = window.SpeechSDK;
      startRecognizeOnceAsyncButton.disabled = false;

      document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('warning').style.display = 'none';

      // in case we have a function for getting an authorization token, call it.
      if (typeof RequestAuthorizationToken === "function") {
          RequestAuthorizationToken();
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Run the page just the same as [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-js-browser) indicated. In a word, while you use sdk you should config `speechConfig.outputFormat=1` so that you can get detailed format of Speech service which includes confident score value.

Result: 
[image]

In your code , seems the undefined error is due to you want to print `SpeechConfig` but that param is defined as `speechConfig` ...

Anyway, to demo get confient score successfully, my code is based on official demo. Hope it helps .

For your code , try the html below :

```
<html>

<body>

<button id='recordButton' onclick = 'test()'>test </button>
</body>

<script src="microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js"></script>
<script>

function test(){
        var SDK =  window.SpeechSDK;
        try {
        AudioContext = window.AudioContext // our preferred impl
            || window.webkitAudioContext   // fallback, mostly for Safari
            || false;                      // could not find.
        if (AudioContext) {
            soundContext = new AudioContext();
          console.log("AudioContext", AudioContext);
        } else {
            alert("Audio context not supported");
        }
        }
        catch (e) {
         console.log("no sound context found, no audio output. " + e);
        }

        console.log("SpeechSDK initialized", SDK);

        var speechConfig = 
          SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("<your subscription key>", 
           "<your service region>");

        speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
        console.log("speechConfig", speechConfig);      

        audioConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
        recognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, 
           audioConfig);
        recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(
        function (result) {
          console.log("result", result); 
          recognizer.close();
          recognizer = undefined;
        },
        function (err) {
          console.log(err);
          recognizer.close();
          recognizer = undefined;
        });
}

</script>
</html>
```

Result: as you can see the result has been logged :

[image]

If my answer is helpful , click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark this answer , thanks !

Comment: Thanks Stanley Gong, the confidence worked with the "boxed" code provided from the Microsoft quick start code. Great help! But, I need to make the speech recognition into a js function so I can apply it to my own code. When I take it out of the HTML provided, I get the undefined, the var is speechConfig and it is undefined, even though it is clearly set to --   `speechConfig = 
          SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, 
           serviceRegion);`

Comment: Hi @Magnus , I modified your code and appended the result in my answer , place the html file at the same folder of the demo so that it can import SDK .

Comment: Hi @Magnus , may I know has this answer solved your issue ?

Comment: Thanks again @Stanley Gong, the function works when its own HTML file and in my main webapp index.html. My structure, though, needs a stand along function that can be called in a js module,  but when I try to use it in another module I get the error - Undefined.

Comment: Hi @Magnus , Have you imported "microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js" in your js code ? Maybe this post will be helpful for you to import external js : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579883/using-external-javascript-files-in-a-js-file